# Looking for a solution using SQL OR PL SQL to get the desired output

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have two tables,

TABLE E

```
e.part  e.source  e.col1  e.col2  e.col3  e.event  ecol4  ecol5    
AAA     XXXXX      a      b       c       e.e1     d      f
```

TABLE F

```
f.part  f.source  f.col1  f.col2  f.col3  f.event  f.col4  f.col5    
AAA     XXXXX      a       b       c       f        null   null
```

I am using UNION to create the final table EF which has column EF.type and other columns created using a CASE statement. If the event is from table F and f.event value is f then EF.type value should be populated as 'ftype'.

Table E and TABLE F have the same part , source , col1 , col2 and col3 values,

TABLE EF

```
ef.part ef.source ef.col1 ef.col2 ef.col3 ef.event ef.c4   ef.c5 ef.c6   EF.type    
AAA     XXXXX     a       b       c       e.e1     d       e     f       null
AAA     XXXXX     a       b       c       f        null    null  null    ftype
```

but I want the final output to be like this:

```
ef.part ef.source ef.col1 ef.col2 ef.col3  ef.event ef.col4case ef.c5case   ef.c6case   EF.type    
AAA     XXXXX     a       b       c        e.e1     d           e           f           ftype
```

to merge the column value from table F and Table E in to a single row in the final table EF.

Comment: Use select max with each column. Null will automatically disappear.

Comment: @XING Look closely at the `ef.event` column, just blindly taking `MAX()` won't work.

Comment: hi tim any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct, you can use `join`:

```
select e.part, e.source, e.col1, e.col2, e.col3,
       e.event, e.col4, e.c5, f.c6case, F.type
from e join
     f
     on e.part = f.part and e.source = f.source and e.col1 = f.col1 and
        e.col2 = f.col2 and e.col3 = f.col3;
```

At least this works for the data in your question.